# how to repeat the direction in listview control

Tags: asp.net

i using datalist control where i am displaying  images under it. that  is( 6 columns * 5  rows)
 for thati have  property repeat direction is "horiztonal" .

like the above design i need  perform in listview Control (i.e )

display like this( here  1,2  are data after 6 data is displayed 7th data start from second row)

```
1 2 3  4  5  6
7 8 10 11 12 13
```

any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 0):

A ListView is better suited for this.

**EDIT**

You can insert basic HTML in the ItemTemplate and use the binding syntax described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150712/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010208-1.aspx

Comment: how  to  define the properties   to repeat direction horiztonal

Answer (score 0):

Try **RepeatColumns** to specify the item count in a row like this :

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 6;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```